# Yii2 Render Partial Form with Different IDs

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to `renderPartial` a `_form` on the screen several times one after another in Yii2 application with having different `ids` for the same fields in each render?

Why would I need this? I have dynamically generated tabs on the screen. When the user clicks on `user/edit/5` I do not redirect but just open a new tab on the screen with the form to edit user inside. When the user clicks on `user/edit/16` I generate another tab with the same form but different data inside and so on. It all works until I reach a field like `date_of_birth` to which I'm trying to attach a `DatePicker`. The tabs make it so that there are several such fields with id of `user-date_of_birth` so the `DatePicker` only works for the very first one of them but not for the rest. That's why I'm looking for hints to generate the same form with `renderPartial` but with different `ids` each time.

Comment: Add what you tried. Specially related to Datepicker

Comment: Not sure how relevant that is but I tried to manually replace the id on each generation using the URL as prefix on the field. It works if you remove or replace the `/` signs as they break the ID field if present, however you lose all the perks with having automatic validation for this field as the controller keeps looking for `user-date_of_birth` to add error messages and/or success/error classes...

Comment: Something else to mention - changing the ID manually is one thing for one field, but if you have to do it for all of them manually (consider having a form entirely of different date fields all connected to DatePickers), that would be quite troublesome. That's why I'm looking for a smart way to do it once for the whole form upon generation/rendering.

Comment: It's unclear for me.  Do you have a problem with datepicker or validation not working or renderPartial not working?

Comment: Problem is with different DatePickers having the same `id` as they are all rendered from the same form on the same page with `renderPartial` (which works). Only the very first rendered DatePicker works, the rest do not.

Comment: This is jquery related problem, are you using yii/jui/Datepicker or any other widget?

Comment: Currently using `yii/jui/Datepicker`, yes. However, while trying to figure out what the problem is, there was a point where I changed the `yii/jui/Datepicker` with `kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker` and I had exactly the same issue with it before going back to the `jui` one.

Comment: And sorry for the many comments but this is definitely relevant: if you generate several `ids` which are the same in the same HTML document, that qualifies as bad by itself, left aside the jQuery, DatePicker, etc.

Comment: You can not generate multiple form like that, instead of tab why you don't try to open form in modal single at a time? Need to call edit action when modal open

Comment: Not an option, client wants tabs so modal windows are not an option in this case.

Comment: can you add the code the way you are using so that we can try locally to check if there is a solution and the actual problem as you are having although the comments describe most of the parts

Answer (score 0):

try to use render instead renderPartial and passing dynamic form ids in the second parameters.

```
return $this->render('_form', [
   'model' => $model,
   'formids' => 'user-'.$id
]);
```

and in your _form.php

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => $formids
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this extension [yii2-dynamicform](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform) . It allows you to render forms on the fly but it has its limitations - for example you can not use it if the form that you render has for example Select2 fields or any other widget fields